# zend where are the controller and view associated

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

Im learning Zend

I have a project basic hello world that is working, I have 2 files, and when pressing a button on my first view, it goes to a second view.

On inspection of the files, I have:

controller\indexController.php   that shows the view  views\scripts\index\index.phtml

I created on CLI another another controller.. controller\about.php with the view
\views\sripts\about\index.phtml

So both are showing in the browser,

but my question is, where are each index associated to each specific controller?
is there a file that links them? or how get the reference for the correct index?

cheers

Comment: Controller name is `about.php` ?

Comment: It will have aboutController.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zend have a structure where the view will have a separte folder for each controller and each action will have a separte phtml file.

for example you have index controller and index action then there will index.phtml file under index folder. In this manner we can have different view folder for each controller.

If you will not define any action then zend will automatcally call the index action and load the index.phtml file of that controller.

Zend frameworks have the autoloader classes that automatcally load the views according to request.

Comment: so the folder is the one that associates the  view? so /foldername/index.phtml will be for controller: foldername.php?

Comment: Yes the folder represent to controller and phtml file to the action

Answer (score 1):

Zend framework automatically call the view from views directly that has the same name as your function

fir example if in your `about` controller you have `indexAction` then zend framework automatically calls index view within views directory. you can pass parameters to view using `view helper`

Thanks